# Use list of variables as arguments when defining php function

Tags: php, function, arguments, variable-variables

I am trying to use a list of variables as arguments when DEFINING a function.  It seems like it should be straight forward, but no.  The callback is easy and I am able to use (...$listOfVariables) to get all needed arguments into callback, but it does not work when defining the function.

I need this because I have 50 different functions that require the use all of the same arguments.  When the list of arguments changes (which it does) I need a central location to make sure all of the different functions use the new list of arguments.  (Again, I already can do this with the callback, but not when I define the function)

Here is how I would normally do it for a few arguments.

```
$var1 = 'var1text';
$var2 = 'var2text';
$var3 = 'var3text';


function funcname($var1, $var2, $var3){

    echo $var1;
}
```

That works fine, but my list of variables changes a lot and is used in many other functions.  I may be going about it the wrong way and I'm open to whatever suggestions you have.  Below is what I need to accomplish.

**EDITED**

1.variables that are defined outside of the function

```
$var1 = 'var1text';
$var2 = 'var2text';
$var3 = 'var3text';
```

2.a variable that contains all of those variables

```
$listOfVar = $var1, $var2, $var3; //***see note below***.
```

3.include list of variables that I can use within the function so I don't have to list them one at a time like I did in the first snippet.

```
function funcname($listOfVar){

    echo $var1;
}
```

the full code I am trying to make work:

```
$var1 = 'var1text';
$var2 = 'var2text';
$var3 = 'var3text';

$listOfVar = $var1, $var2, $var3;

function funcname($listOfVar){

    echo $var1;
}
```

**I realize the commas in the $listOfVar syntax is not correct for this, but what IS the syntax then?  I've tried variable variables ($$) - trying to convert a string to variable name references. I have tried arrays.  I have tried literally hundreds of variations of these and I am just out of ideas for this.  Please help.

Comment: If the list of arguments is so volatile - why not just pass in an array?

Comment: I'd love to.  I have not been successful finding the correct way to do it.  All of my attempts produce nothing.  Can you show me how you would do it using the code I provided?

Comment: Can you explain where `$var1`, `$var2`, etc. are coming from originally? Maybe there's a different way to solve this.

Comment: As outlined above, they are coming from just outside of the function.  If I use the 1st snippet of code I submitted, it works fine.  So, it is not an issue of scope.  I only want to compact the variables into one spot for easier changes.  I need a variable to contain the list of variables for use within the function.  Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know in advance how many variables does the end developper will use on your function, you can use `func_get_args()`. It returns every variables values as an array.

Here is an example of usage:

```
function foo() {
  $arguments = func_get_args();

  return $arguments;
}

print_r(foo(1, 2, 3)); // [1, 2, 3]
print_r(foo('a', 'b', 'c')); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I used this function because you mentioned the fact that you do not know in advance how many parameters the end developper is going to put.

Comment: I do know how many variables there are, it's just that I will be adding and subtracting from the list and I need a place to make a central change to the list...hence a variable that holds all of the variables.

Comment: Was not sure of your issue because you do not provide enough context. Do this [repl.it](https://repl.it/@khalyomede/stackoverflow-53874540) illustrate well your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If instead you use an array for the passed data...

```
function funcname($vars){
    echo $vars[0];
}
```

Although it has advantages not sure if this would be a good idea, but you could also use an associative array...

```
function funcname($vars){
    echo $vars['var1'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In future, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can **understand** your question in order to help you.

Methods have there own scope, meaning unless otherwise declared or passed through, the method will not have access to the variable.

```
class Retriever {
    private static $instance;
    protected $listOfVars = array();

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$instance) return self::$instance;
        self::$instance = new self();
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct() {}

    public function addVar($var) { array_push($this->listOfVars, $var); return $this; }
    public function getVars() { return $this->listOfVars; }
    public function reset() { $this->listOfVars = array(); return $this; }
}

function name($var1, $var2, $var3) {
    echo $var1;
}
function anotherName($var1, $var2) {
    echo $var2;
}

Retriever::getInstance()->addVar("var1text")->addVar("var2text")->addVar("var3text");
name(...Retriever::getInstance()->getVars()); # Output: var1test

Retriever::getInstance()->reset()->addVar("var1text")->addVar("var2text");
anotherName(...Retriever::getInstance()->getVars()); # Output: var2text
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/SjcGe).

Or you can use the list() method

```
function name($listOfVars) { 
    list($var1, $var2) = $listOfVars;
    echo $var1;
}

name(array(‘var1text’, ‘var2text’));
```

Comment: Thank you...I'm already doing that for the callback.  It's the definition that is the pain.  I do not want to have to change the arguments in the definition over and over.  That is where I need the array.

Comment: By definition, do you mean the array key? You cannot use the splat operator if the array is not an assoc array. Perhaps pass in an object? Ill update my answer

Comment: I mean, when I define (name) the function and include arguments, I need it to look like my 2nd example code above.  That is exactly what I need.  I'd prefer not to use keys, indexes, or anything else where I would have to edit the variable names within the function.  Simply a $variable containing $variables....ie  - $allVar = $var1, $var2, $var3.  Seems simple.  Not so much :(

Comment: Im confused on what your expected output is in that case, you want to pass a list of variables into a method and do what with them? You can use join() to join variables onto one another ie: function name($arg) ... name(join(‘ ‘, [$arg1, $arg2...

Comment: I have illustrated exactly what I need in my code above.  I don't know how to explain it any better.  I need a variable that contains all of the variables' names I'm going to be passing into the function.

Comment: It does have access to variables beyond it's scope if it is called into the function.  I only need a list of these.  It may be difficult to answer, which is why I'm asking, but assuming that 'no-one can answer it' is not helpful.  If you have a solution or another way to do it, please let me know and I'd be happy to try it.

Comment: The policies in here have changed.  Abuse isn't necessary.  If you don't have a solution, please move on.

Comment: I updated the answer, there is no abuse. You simply have not provided a MCVE with expected inputs and outputs and you cannot take structured criticism.

Comment: Yes, I did.  It is in my original question.  Please refrain from commenting further.  I have reported your comments already.  I'm here because I need help.  Not interested in anything else.

Comment: "`It does have access to variables beyond it's scope if it is called into the function`" I'll leave it at that, where your reply is :) Try not to contradict yourself further

Comment: The $$ works with 1 variable.  How do I make it work with 2?  I have already used that method before, but not able to do it with more than 1 variable.  I'm sure it's the syntax, but since I don't know how to do it, I'm asking how.

Comment: I'll update my question to use multiple variables now

Comment: Updated, hope it helps. I meant no abuse but your question was unclear, although hard to explain - admittedly. Perhaps by creating a minimal, complete and verifiable example next time you ask a question - it'll help us to understand in future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is a solution I can use.  From what I can see, It still requires that I go to each function that uses those arguments and change the function.  I have many many functions that use a common list of arguments.  I'm just trying to avoid changing every function each time I need to add another argument.

Comment: This is what I need, and what I wrote to begin with.$var1 = 'var1text';
$var2 = 'var2text';
$var3 = 'var3text';

$listOfVar = $var1, $var2, $var3;

function funcname($listOfVar){

    echo $var1;
}         I need to be able to modify $listOfVar and have the function recognize it.  I can do it if I implicitly name each argument.  But, so far, no other way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185569/discussion-between-jaquarh-and-lori).

Comment: Hello @Jaquarh can we chat when you have a moment?

Comment: Sure drop me a chat link: im on my phone at the moment so cannot generate one @Lori

Comment: Lmao or any other means of communication doesn’t bother me @Lori

Comment: I have to have 100pts to open a chat  I will just post my question and see if it gets answered without me getting my *** kicked. @Jaquarh

Comment: Lmao fire it up, as long as it contains a minimal complete and verifiable example, ur untouchable ;) i have a dev whatsapp group if ever its easier to reach out on comms that way, good for ideas etc too but ill leave the ball in your court for that - feel free to post the link to ya question and ill have a look at it @Lori

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188551/discussion-between-lori-and-jaquarh).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could modify your function so that it takes an array instead of multiple arguments.

```
function funcname(array $args){
    foreach ($args as $arg_name => $arg) {
        // do stuff with $arg_name and $arg
    }
    // or refer to a specific argument, like where you would have said $var1, instead...
    $args['var1'];
    // or extract the array within your function to get the keys as variables
    extract($args);
    echo $var1;
    // If you do this, be sure to heed the warnings about extract.
    // Particularly the bit about not extracting $_GET, $_POST, etc.
}
```

Then instead of defining separate variables like

```
$var1 = 'var1text';
$var2 = 'var2text';
$var3 = 'var3text';
```

Create an associative array

```
$text['var1'] = 'var1text';
$text['var2'] = 'var2text';
$text['var3'] = 'var3text';
```

If you have multiple functions that need to use the same varying list of arguments, I think it makes sense to collect them in a class. Then you can pass the associative array of arguments to the class constructor so all the methods will have access to the same set of variables.

```
class SomeFunctions
{

    private $listOfVar = [];

    public function __construct(array $listOfVar) {
        $this->listOfVar = $listOfVar;
    }

    public function funcnameA() {
        foreach ($this->listOfVar as $name => $value) // ...
    }

    public function funcnameB() {
        $this->listOfVar['var1'];
    }
}

$example = new SomeFunctions(['var1' => 'something', 'var2' => 'something']);
$example->funcnameA();
$example->funcnameB();
```

If you need to use these functions as callbacks, you can pass them like this as the callback parameter:

```
functionThatTakesaCallback([$example, 'funcnameB']);
```

Maybe this could be the central location to change the variable list?

Comment: It is a solution, but I'm trying to avoid having to change the way I call the variables within the function.  With my first solution (the one that works above) I can pass the $variable into the function and use it as it is already named.  With this array, I would have to change all of the references within the function to refer to it with an index...or I could be wrong?

Comment: No, not wrong. If you pass an array you'll need to refer to the elements in it by index, unless you use `extract` inside the function. But I guess I don't understand how you'd be referring to distinct variables inside the function without knowing which ones would be passed to it.

Comment: I do know which variables will be passed.  The bottom line is I need a central location to change the list whenever I need to without going to each separate function to change the variables I'm passing.  That's kind of it.  I know this is confusing which is why I'm ripping my hair out.

Comment: Oh, so the problem is not so much one function, but that you have multiple functions that need to take this same varying list of arguments?

Comment: OMG YES.  That is correct!  I guess I wasn't explaining that part well.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, I have a different idea, then. I'll edit this answer. These different functions would be able to be modified by you, right? They aren't defined elsewhere?

Comment: I can modify them.  I'm just trying to save myself 100 edits each time I need to add a new variable to all of the functions.

Comment: I have to study that for awhile since I've never done it that way and it confuses me since different names were used so I'll have to sort it out.  It looks great and I appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully it does end up being helpful and I'm not still misunderstanding. :-) I changed some names there to match the examples in your question a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put your variables in an array and pass the name of the array to your function.

```
$vararray[] = 'var1text';
$vararray[] = 'var2text';
$vararray[] = 'var3text';
funcname($vararray);

function funcname($variable_array){
    echo $variable_array[1];  // will echo var2text
}
```

Comment: So, the problem I have with this is that all of the calls to the variables within the function now have to be changed to include the index [ ].  That is a ton of work.  Ideally, I'd like to use the variable names as are originally named without having to include the index.  So, an array may not be the answer.